# Azure How to get IP Address for a VM in azure golang sdk

Tags: azure, go, networking

Able to fetch details about VM from azure using object mentioned here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/compute/mgmt/2021-03-01/compute@v55.0.0+incompatible#VirtualMachine

Not able to fetch the privateIPAddress for that VM or can't find way to do it. What would be the way to fetch private ip address for any given vm.

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

The IP address is associated with IP configurations of the network interface for the Azure VM, you could find the privateIPAddress for that VM from the network Package.

You may get reference from [type InterfaceIPConfigurationsClientAPI](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go@v55.0.0+incompatible/services/network/mgmt/2021-02-01/network/networkapi#InterfaceIPConfigurationsClientAPI) or [type IPConfigurationPropertiesFormat](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go@v55.0.0+incompatible/services/network/mgmt/2021-02-01/network#IPConfigurationPropertiesFormat)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example that worked for me:

Ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/18705#issuecomment-1196930026

```
ctx := context.Background()
// assumes you authenicated on the command line with `az login`
cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(&azidentity.DefaultAzureCredentialOptions{})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

vmClient, err := armcompute.NewVirtualMachinesClient(subscriptionID, cred, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
nicClient, err := armnetwork.NewInterfacesClient(subscriptionID, cred, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

vm, err := vmClient.Get(ctx, "yourResourceGrp", "yourVmName", nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

for _, nicRef := range vm.Properties.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces {
    nicID, err := arm.ParseResourceID(*nicRef.ID)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    nic, err := nicClient.Get(ctx, nicID.ResourceGroupName, nicID.Name, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for _, ipCfg := range nic.Properties.IPConfigurations {
        if ipCfg.Properties.PublicIPAddress != nil &&
            ipCfg.Properties.PublicIPAddress.Properties != nil {
            publicIP := *ipCfg.Properties.PublicIPAddress.Properties.IPAddress
            fmt.Println("publicIP:", publicIP)
        }
        if ipCfg.Properties.PrivateIPAddress != nil {
            privateIP := *ipCfg.Properties.PrivateIPAddress
            log.Println("privateIP:", privateIP)
        }
    }
}
```